# and error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the mysql error im getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECY * FORM user WHERE username='' AND password='' LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECY * FORM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $row ['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row ['username'];
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else {    
        echo "Invalid login information. Please return to the previous page.";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Someone that can help me? :)
i dont know what im doing working here, cant find the error.

Comment: The correct spelling is `SELECT`, not `SELECY`.

Comment: Also [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: this is the craziest question i have ever seen but its okk when you are learning things

Comment: *Please at least **look at your query** before posting here.*

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECY
```

is a typographical error, try:

```
SELECT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECY * FORM users 
WHERE username='".$username."' 
AND password='".$password."' 
LIMIT 1";
```

Change `SELECY` to `SELECT` and `FORM` to `FROM`.

The correct query should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username='".$username."' 
AND password='".$password."' 
LIMIT 1";
```